# Can a Bluetooth LE device stop advertising and still be connected to and share data?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

I'm writing (and copying) some Bluetooth LE scanner software to find and connect to a heart rate monitor. I used to be able to find this device by using `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` method to perform a generic scan by setting services to `nil`. But in the recent few days, I noticed that my same Bluetooth LE device (my heart rate monitor) can no longer be scanned (perhaps it is not advertising the same way it used to?) but my iPhone can still pair with it under settings and can connect to it with commercial apps such as "Polar Beat" and "Strava".  So what changed?  Can a Bluetooth LE device stop advertising and still be connected to (paired with) and share data as a peripheral?

Comment: Made some slight formatting changes. And removed the first paragraph because IMHO it contained nothing important for this question.

Comment: @mgianzero, did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing is that your device doesn't advertise.

However, it's normal that your iPhone can connect to it because the smartphone executed "bonding" procedure in the past. Bonding is another security procedure than simple pairing. With Bonding, heart rate device and smartphone exchanges keys and store them in a non volatile memory so that they can connect quickly.
With simple pairing the keys are temporary and advertising is needed.

Comment: So you agree that the fact that my heart rate monitor no longer advertises is strange.  Any one have any idea why that is?  But once a Bluetooth device pairs with a client, that client (my iPhone) has executed a "bonding" procedure which allows quick access to this device and this is why my phone can reconnect to it in the future regardless of its inability to advertise.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes ... it's correct. I don't have an iPhone but on my Windows Phone I can "forget" the device so that the saved keys are deleted and bonding canceled.

Comment: You won't believe it!   I found the problem!  I went out today and bought ANOTHER Polar H7 heart rate monitor just to see what happens.  For the first time ever, I got this code to work.  Turns out that my original bluetooth HRM must have been defective!  Thanks ppatierno for your comments.  Now that makes sense what you are saying about the bonding procedure which continues to find my device despite it's lack of advertising.